# How do I get a normal disk going (PERC H710 Mini) with perccli?

Tags: linux, raid, dell-poweredge

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSQan.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9utPQ.jpg

I have a Dell PowerEdge R720 which boots up and has 1.7 TB of drive space but I can't seem to get any of it and use it.  When I try and install Fedora there are no available drives to install it to.

I need to use perccli to run a command to make either all or some of this 1.7 TB available as a drive right?

I ran "perccli64 /c0 add vd each r0 drives=32:1-7"

Thinking this would give me some new drives when I run "df" but it did not.

The images above show output of current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PERC H710 does not support passing plain disk to the OS; you need to create a virtual disk to let the OS recognize it.

Rather than messing with `perccli64` via the command line, it is simpler to access the PERC BIOS interface pressing `CTRL+R` during boot. From here, you can configure a virtual disk with the required redundancy level. Please do ***not*** use single or multi drive RAID-0 unless you ***really*** know what you are doing, because a single fault will bring your server down.

After doing that, you need to format and mount the resulting block device before `df` can list anything.

Comment: ah this makes sense thank you!